# Importing data with VBA in Excel beneath existing table

Tags: excel, vba, import

I want to update my Excel database weekly with new input.

I need to copy the new file to the existing database and put it below it.

I have the base code, but it is hard coded that the imported file is starting on A6. I want it imported on the first empty row beneath my database.

I have this code in my VBA editor in Excel:

```vb
Sub OpenFile()

Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wbTextImport As Workbook

'Make it possible to select file to open
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename

'Create error message box
If fileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected."

Else
    Workbooks.OpenText _
      FileName:=fileToOpen, _
      StartRow:=2, _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=True
                                    
    Set wbTextImport = Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen)
    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad 1")
    wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A6")
    wbTextImport.Close False
End If

End Sub
```

Also, as I stated with `Startrow:=2`, I tried to delete the header of the imported datafile but the header is imported into the datafile.

Comment: What code have you tried.  Please post it here.

Comment: I have tried the code which is in the question starting with sub OpenFile() and ending with End Sub

Comment: There is no code related to a button in your post.

Comment: @freeflow the button is mainly created in excel and linked to the sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will work:

```vb
Sub upload_data()
    Dim WScopy As Worksheet
    Dim WSdest As Worksheet
    Dim desWB As Workbook
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim cRow As Long
    
    Set desWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set WSdest = desWB.Sheets(1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    With Sheets(1)
        cRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:O" & cRow).Copy
        WSdest.Cells(WSdest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This gives the option to browse and insert the file beneath the existing database.